# "Item locked for sharing" in SharePoint 2013 Document library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-designer

I have a document that I'm trying to update the "Title" field for but it's giving me an "Item locked for Sharing" error. It is in the site's default Documents library. I've made sure that "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited" is set to No as seen here: [image]

This is the message I get when I try to edit the properties of the document in the browser. I also get the same error when trying to delete the document, both in the browser and in SharePoint Designer.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can over ride the "locked for sharing" issue and edit this document's properties? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to delete the document and re-upload it. I had to first break inheritance for permissions. Then gave myself full control. Then I checked the document out, deleted it, then uploaded the same document.